# Always returning 0, Google SERP Checker

Tags: php, html

My function searches google for the specific keyword and then checks for the site and then returns the what position it is on google (its for my seo dashboard) but it always return's 0, hopefully some fresh eyes can find the faults

```
<?php
function GoogleSerp($searchquery, $searchurl){
if(!empty($searchquery) && !empty($searchurl))
{
    $query = str_replace(" ","+",$searchquery);
    $query = str_replace("%26","&",$query);

// How many results to search through.

    $total_to_search = 50;

// The number of hits per page.

    $hits_per_page = 10;

// Obviously, the total pages / queries we will be doing is
// $total_to_search / $hits_per_page

// This will be our rank

    $position = 0;

// This is the rank minus the duplicates

    $real_position = 0;

    $found = NULL;
    $lastURL = NULL;

    for($i=0;$i<$total_to_search && empty($found);$i+=$hits_per_page)
    {

// Open the search page.
// We are filling in certain variables -
// $query,$hits_per_page and $start.

      //  $filename = "http://www.google.co.uk/xhtml?q=$query&start=$i&sa=N";
        $filename = "http://www.google.co.uk/m?q=$query&num=$hits_per_page&filter=0&start=$i&sa=N";

        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        if (!$file)
        {
            return "error";
        }
        else
        {

// Now load the file into a variable line at a time

            while (!feof($file))
            {
                $var = fgets($file, 1024);

// Try and find the font tag google uses to show the site URL

                if(eregi("<span class=\"c\">(.*)</span>",$var,$out))
                {

// If we find it take out any <B> </B> tags - google does
// highlight search terms within URLS

                    $out[1] = strtolower(strip_tags($out[1]));

// Get the domain name by looking for the first /

                    $x = strpos($out[1],"/");

// and get the URL

                    $url = substr($out[1],0,$x);
                    $url = str_replace("/","",$url);
                    $position++;

// If you want to see the hits, set $trace to something

                 //   if($trace)return($url."<br>");

// If the last result process is the same as this one, it
// is a nest or internal domain result, so don't count it
// on $real_position

                    if(strcmp($lastURL,$url)<>0)$real_position++;

                    $lastURL = $url;

// Else if the sites match we have found it!!!

                    if(strcmp($searchurl,$url)==0)
                    {
                        $found = $position;

// We quit out, we don't need to go any further.

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
    }

    if($found)
    {
       $result = $real_position;
    }else{
        $result = 0;
    }
}
return $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: I've noticed google sometimes blocks requests from scripts. Isn't there an API that they offer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `urlencode()` instead of the two replaces on the query.

Comment: im sorry could you give me an example

Comment: instead of the two str_replace()'s, use `$query = urlencode($searchquery);`

Comment: Allrite. I tried your script with the original parameters (as i saw in the original source http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/misc_12.php), and it works (getting "2"). The reason of your problem is simple from here: your website is not on the list. Be careful, some client generates special result list, depending on your browser or language. If you want exactly the same result, spoof your browser identification, but it's impossible with `fopen()`. Use `cURL`: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: but i know for a fact im first page.

Comment: Just test it with GoogleSerp("microsoft", "www.microsoft.com"); - i get "1".

Comment: "but i know for a fact im first page." hi, the SERP you see in a browser will be different from what a cookieless scrapping script will see. just output the HTML you get and check it against the result you expect.

Comment: To do this, replace `$var = fgets($file, 1024);` with `$var = fgets($file, 1024);echo $var."\n";`